# How can i delete from the multi table with fk constraint?

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, let's say i have 2 tables.

**tbl_1**

1.id_tbl1 (primary key)

2.name

---

**tbl_2**

1.id_tbl2 (primary key)

2.id_tbl1 (*foreign key*)

3.name

---

P.S If i want to delete data tbl_1 then the **id_tbl1 as fk** will also be **deleted in tbl_2** ... **how can work with php?*

Comment: Use `CASCADE` delete on the FK.

Comment: how can work with php?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is not a "we do the work for you"-service. You supply the code, we help you improve or tell what might be wrong with it. We don't make code for you from scratch. So "How can work with php" (I think you mean: How can I do this in php?) is not ok to ask in this forum if you did not make any attempt.

Comment: yes this i mean...

Comment: my question as an illustration because there are actually previous results, I only see or survey it if it is the same as my case then I can do it according to my needs

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ON DELETE CASCADE` when defining the foreign key. See below:

```sql
create table tbl_1 (
  id_tbl1 int primary key not null,
  name varchar(10)
);

create table tbl_2 (
  id_tbl2 int primary key not null,
  id_tbl1 int,
  constraint fk1 foreign key (id_tbl1) 
    references tbl_1 (id_tbl1) on delete cascade
);
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uEwCvtuLb6aHzV5Zqhnk98/1).

Comment: This is a definition at the database level. If the foreign key is not configured this way, then your application will need to delete the children rows first, then the parent row programatically.